# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in DFS

Tags: java, arrays, exception, depth-first-search

The error line is 69,33,51. The error is Array index out of bound

following is the java code for depth first search alogorithm.

At 69,33,51 it shows array index out of bound exception..

```
public class dfs1 {

    Stack<Integer> st;
    int vFirst;
    int[][] matrix;
    int[] isVisited = new int[3];
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter the no of vertices");
        int size=input.nextInt();
        int[][] matrix=new int[size][size];
        System.out.println("enter the values for matrix");

        for(int row=0;row<size;row++)
        {
            for(int col=0;col<size;col++){
                matrix[row][col]=input.nextInt();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("the adjacency matrix is ");
        for(int row=0;row<size;row++)
        {
            for(int col=0;col<size;col++){
                System.out.println(matrix[row][col]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("enter the start vertex ");
        int start=input.nextInt();
        new dfs1(matrix,size,start);



    }


    public dfs1(int[][] matrix,int size,int start)
    {
        this.matrix = matrix;
        st = new Stack<Integer>();

        int[] node=new int[size];
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            node[i]=i;
        }
        int firstNode = start;
        depthFirst(firstNode,size);
    }
    public void depthFirst(int vFirst,int n)
    {
    int v,i;

    st.push(vFirst);

    while(!st.isEmpty())
    {
        v = st.pop();
        if(isVisited[v]==0)
        {
            System.out.print("\n"+(v+1));
            isVisited[v]=1;
        }
        for ( i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            if((matrix[v][i] == 1) && (isVisited[i] == 0))
            {
                st.push(v);
                isVisited[i]=1;
                System.out.print(" " + (i+1));
                v = i;
            }
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: The line number doesn't really help us. Can you tell us the particular line of code that's causing this issue?

Comment: Can you please clarify what size your matrix is, and what number you are entering for the start vertex?  Also, I strongly recommend stepping through this with a debugger - I'm sure you'd find your problem very quickly if you did so.  Lastly, you really need to tell us which line your problem arises on - there are no line numbers in your listing, so the number doesn't help at all.

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
int[] isVisited = new int[3];
```

But really this array should be AT LEAST `size` long